# What is the correct way to type this function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

**EDIT:**

I'm playing with typing because I would like to avoid returning `Primise<any[]>`, what I'm trying to achieve is to get the correct typing for every position in the returned list based on the list passed as a parameter.

**EDIT 2:**

The error that I was getting has been solved by @outoftouch, but unfortunately, the function typing return is like this:

```
const enabledResources: ({
  firstData: 'Some data',
  secondData: 'Some other data'
} | {
  thirdData: 'Some data',
  fourthData: 'Some other data'
} | undefined)[]
```

The desired result is instead:

```
const enabledResources: [
  { firstData: 'Some data', secondData: 'Some other data' } | undefined,
  { thirdData: 'Some data', fourthData: 'Some other data' } | undefined
]
```

As you can see every list position (in this case position 0 and 1) already have their typing inferred by the Resource list passed as param.

---

### Original Question

I would like to have a function that gets as the first parameter a list of `Resource` that has a field named `getResource` that is a function that returns `Promise<T>`.

The function has to verify if the user is authorized to get that data and, if it is, return that data in the same position that was passed as a parameter, or otherwise returns `undefined`in that list place.

An example of how I would like to use this function is:

```js
const enabledResources = await getPageResources([
  {
    scope: 'some scope', // in User scopes
    getResource: Promise.resolve({ firstData: 'Some data', secondData: 'Some other data' }),
  },
  {
    scope: 'some other scope', // Not in user scopes
    getResource: Promise.resolve({ thirdData: 'Some data', fourthData: 'Some other data' }),
  },
]);

// This should log { firstData: 'Some data', secondData: 'Some other data' }
console.log(enabledResources[0]) 

// This should log undefined
console.log(enabledResources[1])
```

I've tried to achieve that result by writing this function but I got errors in typing:

```js
export type Resource = {
  scope: Scope
  getResource: () => Promise<unknown>
}

export type Role = {
  name: string
  scopes: Scope[]
}

export async function getPageResources<T extends readonly Resource[]>(
  wantedResources: T,
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>
// I get error in the next line that says Type '"getResource"' cannot be used to index type 'T[P]'
): Promise<{ -readonly [P in keyof T]: Awaited<ReturnType<T[P]['getResource']>> | undefined }> {
  const session = await getSession(context)
  const userRole = session?.role as Role | null

  const resourcesToWait = wantedResources.map((e) => {
    const isInUserScopes = userRole?.scopes.includes(e.scope)
    return isInUserScopes ? e.getResource() : undefined
  })

  const resources = await Promise.all(resourcesToWait)

  return resources;
}
```

I actually don't get why this is happening, in my mind `T[P]` should be the element in the list passed as a parameter and I should get the awaited returned type (or undefined), typed in the correct list position.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You've might of forgotten that `P` could be any key of the array. For example, if `P` was `"indexOf"`, `T[P]` would be a function, and functions do not have a `getResponse` method.

You have to explicitly check if `T[P]` is a Resource first with `extends`:

```
): Promise<{
  -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Resource
   ? Awaited<ReturnType<T[P]['getResource']>> | undefined
   : T[P];
}> {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! your suggestion is correct, this solves my error but unfortunately doesn't solve the question. By using the suggestion that you proposed I still can't get the correct typing for every position in the returned list based on the list passed as a parameter, I just get the suggestion that the returned value is a list of params that could be of the first type or of the second one.

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice And here is the part I don't understand. Please try to follow my reasoning here. There are two cases. One is where the scopes you pass to the function are hard coded and known at compile-time. If this is the case, then it is possible to type the function how you want it, and I can update the answer. If it is not hard coded and dynamically given to the function at runtime, then it is not possible. You need to clarify which case it is - hard coded or not.

Comment: Scopes are hardcoded but the return type of `getResource` is not based on the scope and could be anything.